# Isomorphism regarding simple groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

The isomorphic image of a simple group is simple. If G is isomorphic to some group H then G is simple implies H is simple. How can i prove it in the rigorous method

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi：G\rightarrow H$ be an isomorphism.
Suppose $K$ is a normal subgroup of $H$.
Then $\phi^{-1}(K)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
Since $G$ is simple, $\phi^{-1}(K)=\{1\}$

Let $x\in K$. Then $\phi^{-1}(x)\in\phi^{-1}(K)=\{1\}$. This implies that $\phi^{-1}(x)=1$, which means $x=\phi(1)=1$. So we conclude that $K=\{1\}$.